# Run Java spring application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot-admin

I would like run in shell spring-boot-admin-sample application: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample/

But when I compile and run application by commands:

```
mvn package 
java -cp target/spring-boot-admin-sample.jar de.codecentric.boot.admin.SpringBootAdminApplication
```

I get Error: Could not find or load main class de.codecentric.boot.admin.SpringBootAdminApplication

What I have to do for right run??

(I am beginner in Spring and Java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's an executable jar, so you run it with:

```
java -jar target/spring-boot-admin-sample.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it in the background, so that it doesn't exit when you close your terminal etc. try:

```
java -jar target/spring-boot-admin-sample.jar &
```

I usually do this when I'm testing some POC SpringBoot apps locally.